# Можно ли выключить "Переслано из" в Telethon

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telethon

Здравствуйте уважаемые гуру.
Имеется данный код:

```
    from telethon import TelegramClient, events
from config import DESTINATION, API_ID, API_HASH, SESSION, CHATS, KEY_WORDS


client = TelegramClient(SESSION, API_ID, API_HASH)


if name == 'main':
    print("Программа запущена...")

    @client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=CHATS))
    async def new_order(event):
        try:
            print('Найдена новая новость...')
            contain_key_word = False

            for key_word in KEY_WORDS:
                if key_word in event.message.message:
                    contain_key_word = True

            if contain_key_word:
                await client.forward_messages(DESTINATION, event.message)

        except Exception as ex:
            print(f'Exception: {ex}')
            


    client.start()
    client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Данный код грабом по ключевым словам забирает новости с каналов телеграмм.
Можно ли убрать при посте у себя на канале "Переслано из"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С использованием `forward_messages` - нельзя.

В сорцах клиента [TelegramClient](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/master/telethon/_client/telegramclient.py) это явно указано:

> Forwards the given messages to the specified dialog.
>
> If you want to "forward" a message without the forward header
> (the "forwarded from" text), you should use `send_message` with
> the original message instead. This will send a copy of it.

То есть рекомендуется использовать `send_message` для этих целей.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)